# Border stroke not same on left and right side in custom shape

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

I'm trying to create an arrow without bottom line but when I'm applying border stroke. left side and right side border width and color are showing up different. Any idea why this is happening or any different approach to get arrow with border and a color to fill inside the arrow

```
Box(
    modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(height)
        .border(border =  BorderStroke(1.dp,borderColor), shape = DrawTriangleShape())
        .background(color = color, shape = DrawTriangleShape())
)

class DrawTriangleShape : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection, density: Density): Outline {
        val trianglePath = Path().apply {
            moveTo((size.width / 2 ) - with(density) { 10.dp.toPx() }, size.height)
            lineTo((size.width / 2), 0f)
            lineTo((size.width / 2 ) + with(density) { 10.dp.toPx() }, size.height)
        }
        return Outline.Generic(path = trianglePath)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug to, I suggest you [report it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128). Also works fine with `Modifier.width(20.dp)`

Comment: Or it could be just the famous Dukhov's Illusion and they're actually the same width. Plausible?